# on Update, if one of my param is blank, how to delete it from database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I not sure how to delete a param in database, when updating and the param is left blank. Below is my current code-

```
def update
    if !ABC.exists?(:id =>params[:id])
      render json: { errors: @error }, status: 500
    else
      @abc = ABC.find(params[:id])
      if @abc.update(permitted_update_abc_params)
        render json: @abc, status: 200
      else
        render json: @abc.errors.full_messages, status: 500
     end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run

```
obj.update_attributes(:field_name => params[:present_params], :field_name => params[:present_params], :field_name => params[:blank_params])
```

this blank param will replace database field value with existing blank value.